# Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Tags: mac-osx, svn, osx-lion

When i go to http://localhost/repo/myproject/ and enter password this information is displayed:

```
This XML file does not appear to have any style information associated with it. The document tree is shown below.
<D:error xmlns:D="DAV:" xmlns:m="http://apache.org/dav/xmlns" xmlns:C="svn:">
<C:error/>
<m:human-readable errcode="2">Could not open the requested SVN filesystem</m:human-readable>
</D:error>
```

This is my httpd-svn.conf:

```
<Location /repo>
      DAV svn
      SVNPath “/usr/local/repo”
  AuthType Basic

  AuthName "Subversion repository"

  AuthUserFile /etc/users

  Require valid-user

</Location>

$ ls -la
drwxr-xr-x   3 _www  wheel  102 Aug 11 22:22 repo
```

How can i solve this?

Comment: Have you created an SVN repository at that location with `svnadmin create`, and verified that the Apache user can read from it (ie, verify that it's running as _www)?

Comment: Yes it should be correct. Apache should run over www and dir is www. when you type ls -la it's just shown as _www. I get the same error when I go to http://localhost/repo/

Comment: What's your `DocumentRoot` set to?  Also, verify that the permissions for the `www` user have been applied to the items within `repo`.  Also - make sure there's no validity issues with the repo; `svnlook info /usr/local/repo`.

Comment: "$ svnlook info /usr/local/repo/myproject/

2011-08-11 22:22:25 +0200 (Thu, 11 Aug 2011)" Yes everything has permisson www. What's your DocumentRoot set? - Don't know how do I check?

Comment: Somewhere in the Apache config - if the `httpd-svn.conf` file defines a `VirtualHost`, it should be there, otherwise check in the main `httpd.conf`.

Comment: if I try svn list https://192.168.1.2/repo/myproject i get the following: Username: admin
Password for 'admin': 
svn: Could not open the requested SVN filesystem

Comment: <IfDefine MACOSXSERVER>
DocumentRoot /var/empty

Comment: @ShaneMadden let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/1059/discussion-between-mikael-and-shane-madden)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Through troubleshooting in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/1059/2011/8/11/22-24), we found these error logs:

```
[Fri Aug 12 00:56:10 2011] [error] [client 192.168.1.2] (20014)Internal error: Can't open file '\xe2\x80\x9c/usr/local/repo\xe2\x80\x9d/format': No such file or directory
```

Which led us to the quotes in the config being those sneaky, pretty `“”` quotes, instead of config-friendly `""` quotes.  That did the trick!

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem but in my case it was a file permission issue with my hook/post-commit scripts. So I changed the owner of the file and the problem was solved.

Just posting because I came to this post while trying to search for my answer since I received the exact same error message for a whole different problem and it may be useful for someone else.